# Помогите правильно составить предложение

Tags: грамотная-речь

Моё день рождение состоится восемнадцатого мая.Или правильно писать: Мой день рождения состоится восемнадцатого мая.

Comment: Состоится? Наверное, уже состоялся?)   А отмечать будете праздник по этому случаю.  Русский орфографический словарь: день рождения. Пользуйтесь сайтом Грамота.ру, там дается объяснение https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=день%20рождения&mode=all Мой день рождения — восемнадцатого мая.  А дальше приглашение: когда и куда приходить.  Для правки нужен контекст.

Comment: Празднование моего дня рождения состоится 18 мая! Приглашаю всех!/18 мая приглашаю всех в кафе на празднование моего рождения!